# Best approach for limiting rows coming back in SQL when joining for a sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get back a list of users and the total amount that they have ordered. In reality my query is more complex but I think this sums it up. My issue is, if a user made 5 orders for example, I'll get back their name and the total they've ordered 5 times due to the join (having 5 rows in the order table for that user).

What's the recommended approach for when you need to total the records in one table that has multiple rows without requiring many rows to come back? distinct could work but is this the best? (especially when my select chooses more information than what's below)

```
SELECT user.name, sum(order.amount) FROM USER user
    INNER JOIN USER_ORDERS order
       ON (user.user_id = order.user_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT u.name, SUM(o.amount)
FROM USER u JOIN
     USER_ORDERS uo
     ON u.user_id = uo.user_id
GROUP BY u.name, u.user_id;
```

Note that this has included `user_id` in the `GROUP BY`, just in case two users have the same name.

If you want all users, even those without orders, then you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.name, SUM(o.amount)
FROM USER u LEFT JOIN
     USER_ORDERS uo
     ON u.user_id = uo.user_id
GROUP BY u.name, u.user_id;
```

Or a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.name,
       (SELECT SUM(o.amount)
        FROM USER_ORDERS uo
        WHERE u.user_id = uo.user_id
       )
FROM USER u;
```

Comment: Group by looks good, but when I put more columns in my select then it also needs to go in my group by which then results in multiple rows at times.

Comment: @rcoin . . . (1) Yes.  The `GROUP BY` must be consistent with the `SELECT` in an aggregation query. 
 (2) This answers the question that you actually asked.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.  (3) The correlated subquery gives you much more flexibility because there is no `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the analytic version of SUM.

```
SELECT u.name, SUM(o.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY u.name)
FROM USER u JOIN
     USER_ORDERS uo
 ON u.user_id = uo.user_id;
```